# how to get celery task state?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I am new to Celery and Django. I got the task id using

```
task_id = task.request.id
```

but not able to get the task state.

Any suggestion to get the task state? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got the status of task as below

**task.py**

```
from celery.result import AsyncResult

result = task_name.AsyncResult(task_name.request.id)
taskStatus = result.state
```

**celeryconfig.py**

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = False
CELERY_TRACK_STARTED = True
```